# Setting background-image to fixed, but only show it inside a div

Tags: html, css, graphics

I'm trying to reproduce this layout and theme : [Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEias.jpg)

There is a global background that is a radial-gradient image combined with a transparent texture. That's the easy part.
The hard part for me is to set "holes" in the texture background, as you can see in the picture above with the sidebar and the content cells.

My current attempt is to use a fixed ::before for each "hole" div, with the gradient as background-image. Then only display that background inside the div.

So far I have this :

```css
html, body, #finder {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#finder {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#finder-sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 290px;
}

#finder-sidebar::before {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -2;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 24% 14%,rgb(57, 79, 0) 0%,rgb(48, 70, 0) 21.5%,rgb(39, 61, 85) 50.2%,rgb(34, 58, 84) 83.6%,rgb(26, 44, 63) 100%);
}

#finder-title {
  min-height: 86px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: rgba(28,206,156,.8);
}

#finder-navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#finder-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/dark-denim-3.png");
}

#finder-body::before {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -2;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 24% 14%,rgb(57, 79, 102) 0%,rgb(48, 70, 94) 21.5%,rgb(39, 61, 85) 50.2%,rgb(34, 58, 84) 83.6%,rgb(26, 44, 63) 100%);
}

#finder-header {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 86px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#finder-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#cell {
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#cell::before {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 24% 14%,rgb(57, 79, 102) 0%,rgb(48, 70, 94) 21.5%,rgb(39, 61, 85) 50.2%,rgb(34, 58, 84) 83.6%,rgb(26, 44, 63) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id='finder'>
  <div id='finder-sidebar'>
    <div id='finder-title'>
    </div>
    <div id='finder-navbar'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='finder-body'>
    <div id='finder-header'>
    </div>
    <div id='finder-content'>
      <div id='cell'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem : the fixed ::before backgrounds are either invisible or overlay everything. How can I manage this to get the correct outcome ?

Comment: why don't you use bootstrap's parallax ?

Comment: Because it is nothing to do with my issue.